# Why does HTTP's PUT method mandate a 201 Created/204 No Content split?

Tags: http

HTTP includes this in its [definition of the `PUT` method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4):

> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the PUT successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the user agent by sending a 201 (Created) response. If the target resource does have a current representation and that representation is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed representation, then the origin server MUST send either a 200 (OK) or a 204 (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the request.

The standard — pretty strongly — mandates that the server *MUST* return a 201 if the target resource is created. **But why?** Is there some good reason to inform the client that the PUT was a creation, as opposed to a modification?

From my perspective as a server writer, this is an onerous requirement: the storage service I'm writing to supports upserting, but doesn't actually give me any indication of whether the upsert was an update or an insert, unfortunately. I can query beforehand, but the underlying service *also* doesn't give me atomicity around that query and the subsequent upsert, *and* that adds an extra round-trip to the underlying service, all just to determine what status code to send.

Is there a good reason why I shouldn't just ignore the spec here, and just always return one of `201 Created` or `204 No Content` regardless of whether it was semantically a create?

Comment: I'm also leaning toward disregarding the spec here.  I can't find anything on google explaining the decision, and I also have the convenience of an upsert at my disposal without a "created/updated" return status.  We should be able to take advantage of the idempotent semantics while disregarding whether a create or update specifically occurred.  IMO the spec SHOULD PATCH MUST to SHOULD

Comment: If the client (for whatever reason e.g. showing a different result message or navigating to some other page) needs to know that a new resource was created (instead of modified) it can use the status code for that instead of trying to check for existence by doing a GET before the PUT.
Of course if your backend doesn't provide any easy means to do so it's your call whether it's worth it -- mainly depending on the target audience of your API and their expectations